# SPARQL queries not working for loaded N-Quads dataset in Fuseki2

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki, n-quads

In Fuseki2 I can load n-quads dataset without any problem but the sparql queries not working.
A basic simple query given below also not giving any result

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
LIMIT 25
```

But for loaded rdf dataset the sprql queries working well.
i started the fuseki2 in standalone mode using following command

```
 java -Xmx10240M -jar fuseki-server.jar --update --loc=Data /dataset1
```

I have 16 GB memory in my machine so i allocated 10GB for the fuseki.
Until now i didn't try java api i just run the fuseki in standalone mode using above command and from the web browser i am doing everything.

Is there any way to run sparql queries on loaded n-quads dataset

Comment: Try this query: "SELECT * { {?s ?p ?o} UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } }"

Comment: Unrelated: That's too much heap and actually can slow Fuseki down.  Try 4G. Fuseki uses non-heap memory.